# Excel getting stuck

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, freeze

This is Excel 2013 (32-bit) on Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit). The problem I'm facing is that Excel often (but not always) gets stuck when I start typing in a cell. The freeze continues for maybe 5 or 6 seconds (and is system-wide) and Excel would then resume normally. I have checked the following:

1. Stopped all unnecessary services/background programs.
2. No COM add-ins are active in Excel.
3. I used procmon.exe to see what causes the freeze. Here are the relevant lines:

1:07:25.3513382 RegQueryKey HKLM    BUFFER TOO SMALL    Query: Name, Length: 0

1:07:25.3513532 RegQueryKey HKLM    SUCCESS Query: Name

1:07:25.3513940 RegQueryKey HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\ClickToRun  SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x100

1:07:25.3514113 RegOpenKey  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CTF\KnownClasses NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed

1:07:25.3514334 RegOpenKey  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CTF\KnownClasses    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed

The next entry in procmon has timestamp set to 1:07:31 (6 seconds), during which the entire system remains unresponsive. Does this give anyone any clue as to what is going on?

Comment: My Excel 2010 32bit (Win 7 Pro) sometimes breaks down completely, if I have too many (overlapping) conditional formats. This can happen after frequent move, cut/copy (paste) operations. After cleaning up the conditional formattings, I can edit the cells again.

Comment: @fheub: I do not need to do anything special to reproduce the above. Opening a default blank workbook and trying to type 1 in the first cell (A1) can produce this for me.

Comment: I can do the following interesting sequence too: Start Excel, Type "a" in A1 ("a" appears without hanging), press ESC, type "a" again (gets stuck for 5-6 seconds, then "a" appears), press ESC, type "a" again ("a" appears without hanging) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried disabling automatic formula calculation? (formulas ribbon, far right)

If this works, then it's probably that your workbook just has a lot of intense formulas to calculate (array formulas, or lookups referencing a whole column for example)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the case. I can produce this behavior on empty workbooks too.

Comment: what conditions produce this?

Comment: Very odd for things to happen on blank workbooks... have you done anything funny with your `personal.xlsb` file? this can hold macros and things which could be running in the background when certain things happen. Otherwise I'd also double-check there's nothing outside of excel trying to hijack any functionality (such as malware or a keylogger, if you've got nothing legit which would do such a thing)